# SQL case when using IN clause, clean way?

Tags: sql, sql-server, arrays, case

Hi all I am trying to use an IN clause base on a condition. I don't want 2 separate SQL statements and was hoping for an inline solution. I want to say, if the string is blank then don't apply the IN query, however if it isn't then use it. I know I can do an IF statement but I think that smells but unsure of another way of doing it? Googling around showed that the IN doesn't support case keyword...

Thanks in advance, Onam.

```
declare @PartStockID nvarchar(50)
set @PartStockID = '32919,40335'

select top 10 * from PMS_PartStock
where 
(@PartStockID != '' AND PartStockID in (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Split_List_Int(@PartStockID)) OR PMS_PartStock.PartStockID = PMS_PartStock.PartStockID )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `AND` to `OR` and `!=` to `=`

```
where 
(@PartStockID = '' OR PartStockID in (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Split_List_Int(@PartStockID)) OR PMS_PartStock.PartStockID = PMS_PartStock.PartStockID )
```

Comment: and hope that the query analyzer is clever enough to figure out if that first part is either always true or always false (and skip the second part if possible). Otherwise, two queries might be better. (But it should do that).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't recognize the syntax of '==', I didn't know you could do that in SQL... is this a new feature?

Comment: yes, but even if query analyzer will not be clever enough, it will work correctly, just a bit slower

Comment: My query still returning all items even though my variable @PartStockID is NOT empty... I want my list to be filtered if there is a value in my variable... I imagine two queries based on an IF statement is the only way?

Comment: Are you sure @PartStockID is empty? or null?

Comment: Sorry sorted it, a little bit was missing on the end: where 
(@PartStockID = '' OR PartStockID in (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Split_List_Int(@PartStockID)) OR (PMS_PartStock.PartStockID = PMS_PartStock.PartStockID AND @PartStockID = ''))

Comment: Good, I am glad I could be helpful

Comment: Cheers mate that was an incredibly quick answer lol :) thanks again, I get a little lost with brackets and SQL :(